# Question view count

Tags: support, questions

Sometimes I notice that the number of views for a question I asked is 1, right after I posted the question. Does the view count include also me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen questions with zero views, so I think it includes you!

Comment: It seems so. I have created a question, and the view count is already 1 after only 20 seconds. Or that, or Speedy Gonzales really exists.